# Show higher resolution images on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Good morning peoples.

I just want to show higher resolutions images on hover of lower resolutions images. I want to make a rule or any type of function that can do this work dynamically, I mean I cannot just put on every image a hover effect and changing the src every where.

I have an idea if it would be useful,

I can put all small resolutions images in a folder called images/small, and all large images in folder called images/large, so can we just make a function that can change just change "images/**SMALL**" to "images/**LARGE**"

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: using hover and then call with ajax...

Comment: Yes, jQuery hover function can do that.

Comment: @Pugazh Can I have that code ?

Comment: How fluent in jQuery are you?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many plugins are available which is written in JQuery/JavaScript. I can name few of them here which I used on various projects

1. [Cloud Zoom](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom)
2. [JQuery HoverPluse Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-jQuery-Plugin-To-Zoom-Images-On-Hover-HoverPulse/)
3. [AJAX-Zoom](http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example20.php)

I hope this will help you. If you want you can write your own plugin too which could go in similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Hover Pulse plugin is pretty good, it's done what I've needed in the past and looks like it is what your looking for. Usage is simple too:

[Check out this jsFiddle I made as a demo for you](http://jsfiddle.net/lissy93/dc9wk2dq/)

**1. Include the jQuery and hover pulse plugin**

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/jquery.hoverpulse.js"></script>
</head>
```

**2. Add classes or id's to your images to use as selectors**

```
<div id="thumbs">
                <div class="thumb"><img src="http://malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/images/beach1.jpg" width="64" height="64" /></div>
                <div class="thumb"><img src="http://malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/images/beach2.jpg" width="64" height="64" /></div>
                <div class="thumb"><img src="http://malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/images/beach3.jpg" width="64" height="64" /></div>
    </div>
```

**3. Add the jQuery code at the bottom of the document just before the clossing  tag.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.thumb img').hoverpulse({
        size: 40,  // number of pixels to pulse element (in each direction)
        speed: 400 // speed of the animation 
    });
});
```